# Contentful entry field conversion?

Tags: data-conversion, contentful

I'm using contentful and want to convert some entry fields into more human readable content.

For example: I have a content type that has a field "location" that stores latitude and longitude. For us to display that in the app, i need that data to be converted into an adress. This can be done using the Google Maps API. How can I use the Google Maps API (or a third party API for other conversion cases)  without having to build my own backend which retrieves data from contentful and then converts it.

Is there a way to do this with contentful?

Kind regards,
Erik

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this with Contentful, it just allows you to store and retrieve that data.

But depending on your use case you could also use the Google Maps client side SDKs (iOS/Android/JS) to do this.

Comment: Okay, that's a clear answer! Is there any intention of this becoming a feature in the future for contentful? Because this kind of limits developers to the available field types. It is highly inefficient to have all the mobile devices doing the conversion work, contacting the Google API in this example.